# IOT with MEAN - Together

Tags: mean, iot

MEAN stack and IOT are the current trending  hot topics. Can these two be used together? If yes then in what way?

How can these technologies be used together?

Sweta.

Answer (score 1):

By saying MEAN.js you are including things that are not strictly in the IoT terrain. Angular for example has little to do with anything.

On the web front end you need to implement a javascript library like Paho.js that will use the MQTT protocol to connect to a broker and start aggregating messages from connected devices.

Express has little to do as well as you are not exposing a Restful interface but connecting low level through a broker. A good solution in Node.js is Mosca.

Mongo is good for dumping data from devices.

I have written a [tutorial using Node.js and iOS](http://karmadust.com/internet-of-things-with-ios-node-js-and-mqtt/) so have a look and you might find it interesting.

Answer (score 1):

Mean stack is the combination of the frontent web  frameworks like angularjs,emberjs,knockoutjs,backbonejs , javascript's backend server called nodejs and using the mongodb at top. so using these frameworks and library  will make a mean stack developer.
IoT pronounced as Internet of things. iot is recently used for connected electronics devices .basically it is a form of running your program inside the electronic chip and mostly trying to connect the devices.making control on devices using the programmed chip. there are separate IDE's are avaialble for developing and testing the programme on embeded chip.
you can use angularjs as a frontend(making your GUI) for your IoT'S application.

Answer (score 0):

#### Yes, you can.

As a fact is has been done before. And in other frontend frameworks too. [Here](https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2013/03/home-automation-with-angularjs-and-node-js-on-a-raspberry-pi/) there is an example for home automation.
You can find even a [yeoman](http://yeoman.io/) generator for such projects [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/generator-angular-arduino).

> [**Disclaimer: I work here**] [Netbeast](https://github.com/netbeast/dashboard) started managing devices and creating a system of plugins on top
>   of a **MEAN** app and RESTful communications. (Now we use a **MERN**
>   stack, with react and MQTT over websockets to control networks and
>   update values in real time.)

To mention other places where you can find examples of current projects using MEAN to run IoT networks I encourage you to join angular, arduino and raspberry communities, as well as taking a tour over [producthunt.com](https://www.producthunt.com/search?q=internet+of+things), [hackster.io](https://www.hackster.io/) and other maker sites such as the previously mentioned Netbeast [forum](http://forum.netbeast.co/).

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can make an IoT platform with the MEAN stack. Typically the sensors are low cost sensors and are constantly transmitting small amounts of data in MQTT or TCP protocols. With Node.js you can write, servers for such applications very easily.

Mongo is useful if you have unstructured data, which could happen if you work with multiple sensors. If you don't need unstructured data structures, SQL is sufficient.

All the data that you get from devices, finally needs to be consumed via applications. Express and Angular are great platforms to manage web applications.

You can read a little more about IoT platforms in MEAN at http://blog.yatis.io/scalable-iot-platform-mean-stack/